# Java 8 lambda: given a list, remove all elements except for the first element, without creating a new list

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, java-8, java-stream

As the title says, I would like to use Java 8's streams & lambda expressions in order to remove all the elements but the first one from a list. So that would change the original list to practically a singleton.

Usually I see lambda expression like this (assuming `list` is `ArrayList<Sting>`):

```
list.removeIf(string -> string.endsWith("suffix"));
```

So the condition is on the element but not on the index of the element. Is it possible with Java 8's API to write a predicate on the index? Something like this:

```
list.removeIf(index -> index > 0);
```

When I try something like this:

```
list.stream().limit(1);
```

the problem is, that it does not change the original list. So I have to collect the elements on the stream into a new list.

Comment: Why do you want to use streams and lambda expressions for this? (They don't normally modify the existing list, for a start.) I'd probably remember the first element, clear the collection, then add the first element back...

Comment: Why not use `list.subList(0,1)`?

Comment: What's wrong with [List#sublist(0, 1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int))? Streams/lambdas are useful and all, but Java hasn't become a pure functional language or anything.

Comment: In-place modification: `list.subList(1, list.size()).clear()`

Comment: @ Jon Skeet purely for educational purpose.

Comment: @rapt top voted answer in the duplicate link is what you want.

Comment: @user432, try to avoid an `if` call every iteration. There are easier methods.

Comment: @user432: That's terrible. Looping over the list inside looping over the list to get the first element of the list. Use `list.get(0)` or `list.sublist`.